# UIActionSheet showFromRect Autorotation

Tags: ios, ios5

I'm showing a `UIActionSheet` like this:

```
-(void)accessoryPressed:(id)sender{
    //Omitted unnecessary objects

    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:titleString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete" otherButtonTitles:@"Upload", nil];
    //actionSheet.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
    actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
    actionSheet.tag = ((UIButton*)sender).tag;
    [actionSheet showFromRect:[(UIButton*)sender frame] inView:[(UIButton*)sender superview] animated:YES];
}
```

Where the `sender` object is a `UIButton` embedded in a `UITableViewCell`'s accessory view.

The problem is when the iPad is rotated the actionsheet is not resizing (I don't expect it to actually RESIZE but I want it to be in the correct X,Y) I tried setting the AutoResizingMask to FlexibleLeft and FlexibleTop but it doesn't seem to change.

**Does anyone have any idea on how to get the actionSheet to point to the `accessoryView` after auto-rotation?**

Here is what it looks like:

Before Rotation-
[image: Before Rotation]

After Rotation - 
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a shame `UIKit` doesn't properly handle this for us. In my own app I handle this by implementing the `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` method in my view controller and reshow any popover again using the updated frame of the view.

Comment: Ok, I guess that's what I'll have to do then. It might be nice to have it animate to the new button xy. Thanks.

Comment: `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` gives better results to handle this case.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this is a generalized variation on @rmaddy's. It's a little complicated, but if you want a general solution to getting callbacks for rotation, this may help. I have a main container view controller (if you want, think of this as a subclass of UINavigationController) in which I implement:

```
- (void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;
{
    [[SMRotation session] viewControllerWillRotate];
}

- (void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation;
{
    [[SMRotation session] viewControllerDidRotate];
}
```

In the classes where I need it (typically non-view controller classes), I register callbacks. E.g.,

```
[[SMRotation session].willRotate addTarget:popTip withSelector:@selector(willRotateHelp)];
[[SMRotation session].didRotate addTarget:popTip withSelector:@selector(didRotateHelp)];
```

The SMRotation class is as follows:

```
//
//  SMRotation.h
//  Petunia
//
//  Created by Christopher Prince on 5/10/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Spastic Muffin, LLC. All rights reserved.
//

// The reason for this class is because I don't, in general, appear to be able to get willRotate notifications from iOS. UIDevice only seems to support didRotate notifications.

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "NSObject+TargetsAndSelectors.h"

@interface SMRotation : NSObject

+ (instancetype) session;

// Call these back from the same named methods in your main view controller.
- (void) viewControllerWillRotate;
- (void) viewControllerDidRotate;

// Use these in other classes to get rotation callbacks. There are no parameters passed to the callbacks.
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSObject<TargetsAndSelectors> *willRotate;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSObject<TargetsAndSelectors> *didRotate;

@end
```

and

```
//
//  SMRotation.m
//  Petunia
//
//  Created by Christopher Prince on 5/10/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Spastic Muffin, LLC. All rights reserved.
//

#import "SMRotation.h"

@interface SMRotation()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSObject<TargetsAndSelectors> *willRotate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSObject<TargetsAndSelectors> *didRotate;
@end

@implementation SMRotation

+ (instancetype) session;
{
    static SMRotation* s_sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        s_sharedInstance = [self new];
        [s_sharedInstance setup];
    });

    return s_sharedInstance;
}

- (void) setup;
{
    self.willRotate = [NSObject new];
    [self.willRotate resetTargets];
    self.didRotate = [NSObject new];
    [self.didRotate resetTargets];
}

- (void) viewControllerWillRotate;
{
    [self.willRotate forEachTargetInCallbacksDo:^(id target, SEL selector, NSMutableDictionary *dict) {
        [target performVoidReturnSelector:selector];
    }];
}

- (void) viewControllerDidRotate;
{
    [self.didRotate forEachTargetInCallbacksDo:^(id target, SEL selector, NSMutableDictionary *dict) {
        [target performVoidReturnSelector:selector];
    }];
}

@end
```

The TargetsAndSelectors category is as follows:

```
//
//  NSObject+TargetsAndSelectors.h
//  Petunia
//
//  Created by Christopher Prince on 5/11/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Spastic Muffin, LLC. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

// Allow an object to have a collection of target's, and selectors that can be called as needed.

@protocol TargetsAndSelectors <NSObject>

// The only reason I have made all of these optional is to avoid the compiler complaining. I'm using this protocol just to document the fact that I'm making these methods available (through the NSObject (TargetsAndSelectors) category) in a particular class.
@optional

// Clear all target/selector's. This method must be called *before* any call to addTarget or to other methods of this category, for a particular instance.
- (void) resetTargets;

/**
 *  Add/remove a callback.
 *
 *  @param target Target object.
 *  @param selector Method to call on the target object.
 *
 *  @return Dictionary that was just added to the callbacks property for this target and selector.
 */
- (NSMutableDictionary *) addTarget: (id) target withSelector: (SEL) selector;
- (void) removeTarget: (id) target withSelector: (SEL) selector;

/**
 *  Convenience method to enable calling each of the callbacks in sequence.
 */
- (void) forEachTargetInCallbacksDo: (void (^)(id target, SEL selector, NSMutableDictionary *dict)) block;

// Elements are NSMutableDictionary's, with keys:
// Value of this is a target (id) embedded in a WeakRef object, so that if the target is deallocated, we don't retain a reference that object.
#define TARGETS_KEY_WEAK_TARGET @"weakTarget"
// Value of this is formatted as an NSString
#define TARGETS_KEY_SELECTOR @"selector"
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSArray *callbacks;

@end

@interface NSObject (TargetsAndSelectors)<TargetsAndSelectors>
@end
```

and

```
//
//  NSObject+TargetsAndSelectors.m
//  Petunia
//
//  Created by Christopher Prince on 5/11/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Spastic Muffin, LLC. All rights reserved.
//

#import "NSObject+TargetsAndSelectors.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>
#import "WeakRef.h"

@implementation NSObject (TargetsAndSelectors)

static char kCallbacksKey;

- (void) setCallbacks:(NSArray *)callbacks
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &kCallbacksKey, callbacks, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
}

- (NSArray *) callbacks
{
    NSArray *theCallbacks = (NSArray *) objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &kCallbacksKey);
    return theCallbacks;
}

- (void) resetTargets
{
    self.callbacks = [NSMutableArray new];
}

- (NSMutableArray *) mutableCallbacks
{
    NSMutableArray *mutableCallbacks = (NSMutableArray *) self.callbacks;
    return mutableCallbacks;
}

- (NSMutableDictionary *) addTarget: (id) target withSelector: (SEL) selector;
{
    WeakRef *weakTarget = [WeakRef toObj:target];

    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [@{TARGETS_KEY_WEAK_TARGET: weakTarget,
                                   TARGETS_KEY_SELECTOR: NSStringFromSelector(selector)} mutableCopy];
    [[self mutableCallbacks] addObject:dict];
    return dict;
}

- (void) removeTarget: (id) target withSelector: (SEL) selector;
{
    NSString *stringSelector = NSStringFromSelector(selector);
    NSDictionary *dictToRemove = nil;

    for (NSDictionary *dict in [self mutableCallbacks]) {
        NSString *dictSelectorString = dict[TARGETS_KEY_SELECTOR];
        WeakRef *weakTarget = dict[TARGETS_KEY_WEAK_TARGET];
        if (weakTarget.obj == target && [dictSelectorString isEqualToString:stringSelector]) {
            dictToRemove = dict;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (dictToRemove) {
        [[self mutableCallbacks] removeObject:dictToRemove];
    }
}

- (void) forEachTargetInCallbacksDo: (void (^)(id target, SEL selector, NSMutableDictionary *dict)) block;
{
    // 5/10/15; Making a copy of the callbacks array in case one of the callbacks calls removeTarget above.
    NSArray *copyOfCallbacks = [self.callbacks copy];

    for (NSMutableDictionary *dict in copyOfCallbacks) {
        NSString *dictSelectorString = dict[TARGETS_KEY_SELECTOR];
        SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(dictSelectorString);

        WeakRef *weakTarget = dict[TARGETS_KEY_WEAK_TARGET];

        // Going to just skip by any target that is nil, i.e., has been deallocated. A better idea would be to remove that target from the array...
        if (weakTarget.obj) {
            block(weakTarget.obj, selector, dict);
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Finally, WeakRef is:

```
//
//  WeakRef.h
//  Petunia
//
//  Created by Christopher Prince on 9/1/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Spastic Muffin, LLC. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface WeakRef : NSObject

+ (instancetype) toObj: (id) obj;
+ (id) from: (WeakRef *) weakRef;

@property (nonatomic, weak) id obj;

@end
```

and

```
//
//  WeakRef.m
//  Petunia
//
//  Created by Christopher Prince on 9/1/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Spastic Muffin, LLC. All rights reserved.
//

#import "WeakRef.h"

@implementation WeakRef

+ (instancetype) toObj: (id) obj;
{
    WeakRef *result = [WeakRef new];
    result.obj = obj;
    return result;
}

+ (id) from: (WeakRef *) weakRef;
{
    return weakRef.obj;
}

@end
```

Guess some of this should go on Github...